# Django Formset: object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset, django-formwizard

I think I'm almost there, but the last part just doesn't want to work :(. I hope you can help as I'm not seeing it anymore after 2 days.

Within my FormWizard I'm trying to (1) show a Formset based on a Slider Input in a previous set (setting the Extra value) and (2) in each Form within the Formset I want to show a ChoiceField (forms.Select) based on a Text-input in a previous step.

With a lot of searching on stackoverflow I am able to do step 1. Step 2 is almost working, except for the fact that the ChoiceField doesn't update with the new values from the Text-input. This is my code in views.py:

```
class FormWizardView(LoginRequiredMixin, SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'test/test.html'


    def get_form_initial(self, step):

        if step == 'formset_step':
            form_class = self.form_list[step]
            data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('slider_step')
            if data is not None:
                # To set the extra value in formset based on slider input
                extra = data['number_slider'] 
                form_class.extra = extra

                # To set the ChoiceField value in formset based on text-input
                form1_cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('text_input_step')
                formset = form_class().forms
                for form in formset:
                    if form1_cleaned_data:
                        form.fields['text_input'].choices = [item for item in form1_cleaned_data.items()]
                        # Print form to test if the form updates
                        print(form)
                return formset

        return super(FormWizardView, self).get_form_initial(step)


    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        do something

        return something
```

I'm trying to return the formset, but I get the error `'TestForm' object has no attribute 'get'`. I am probably returning the wrong thing here, but whatever I try to return, it doesn't work. Returning `super(FormWizardView, self).get_form_initial(step)` just gives me the empty ChoiceField and returning the form gives me the error `object of type 'TestForm' has no len()`.

I also printed out the form in my console, and that seems to work properly. Does anyone know what I should return in order to get the populated ChoiceField?

Many thanks!

**EDIT:**
Thanks for your answer! When I modify my get_form:

```
def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        if step == 'formset_step':
            form_class = self.form_list[step]
            data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('slider_step')
            if data is not None:
                # To set the extra value in formset based on slider input
                extra = data['number_slider'] 
                form_class.extra = extra

                # To set the ChoiceField value in formset based on text-input
                form1_cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('text_input_step')
                formset = form_class().forms
                for form in formset:
                    if form1_cleaned_data:
                        form.fields['text_input'].choices = [item for item in form1_cleaned_data.items()]
                        # Print form to test if the form updates
                        print(form)

        return super(FormWizardView, self).get_form(step, data, files)
```

I get the error `['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']`. When browsing through StackOverflow it seems a template problem (and specifically not setting `{{ wizard.management_form }}`, but I took the plain code from the Django FormTools doc which should normally work. In my template I have this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block head %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ wizard.form }}
{% endif %}
</table>
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{%
˓→trans "first step" %}</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{%
˓→trans "prev step" %}</button>
{% endif %}
<input type="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Am I not seeing something in the template or my get_form function not correct? Many thanks for looking at my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Method `get_form_initial` from form wizard should return a dictionary with initial data for the form that will be created, not the form itself. If you want to modify whole form, try modifying `get_form` method instead.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer GwynBleidD! My initial plan was to put this in get_form, but I got an error when even trying to set the extra parameter. Could you please take a look at my edit on my question above?